# I can install a shared printer within a workgroup only using IP

Tags: windows-xp, network-printer

Yesterday I faced a problem for the first time.

I was working on a workgroup where all the clients have Windows XP Professional. I shared a printer on a client then followed the wizard to add this printer on other clients.

Unluckily I saw the computer name with the shared printer with a plus symbol on its left but I was not able to click it in order to see the shared printer. I've been able to install this printer by writing on each client:

```
\\ip_address_of_pc_with_printer\name_of_shared_printer.
```

I'd like to know the reason of this problem. Is it a DNS problem or something else?

Comment: It sounds like a permissions issue. For the record, in a workgroup, you are not recolving by DNS.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. :) Please forgive me but I'm not a guru of pcs. What kind of permission would I have to check?